# Security in widely used SMPP in telco

Tags: ssl, sms, tls1.2, smpp, telecommunication

SMPP is a plain text kind of protocol to interfere between Telco SMSC and external applications (ESMEs). Now a days information security has become crucial and hence there needs data encryption while traveling over SMPP protocol. Similar to https/sftp is there any standard of Secured SMPP which will use TLS/SSL?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believes there is a standard although there are several papers and discussions on the topic if you search.

Certain SMSC's so support SSL security, such as:

- Apache Camel (open source) - https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/smpp-component.html#_uri_format
- SMS Center (commercial) - http://smsccenter.com/smpp.html

It's worth noting that even if the connection to the SMSC is secure, the content within the operators network is typically not encrypted and can be read and analysed by the network and its employees so depending on your application SMS may not be the right mechanism for your needs.